# Count Prometheus metrics of a given time frame matching a certain pattern

Tags: prometheus

Consider a Prometheus Exporter for a task runner which outputs its metrics for succeeded, recurring jobs as

```
sometool_jobs_succeeded{job_name="joba-123456"} 1
sometool_jobs_succeeded{job_name="joba-987654"} 1
sometool_jobs_succeeded{job_name="jobx-411235"} 1
```

I want to setup a Prometheus Alert if no job of type `joba` succeeded within the last 2 hours.

My first approach was to use the Alert expression

```
sum(increase(sometool_jobs_succeeded{job_name=~"^joba-.+"}[2h])) < 1
```

But as there is never a metric of type `sometool_jobs_succeeded` with a value other than `1`, `increase` didn't work properly (there was no increase if the metric just *appeared*).

How can I realize my query? Is it somehow possible to *count* the resulting metrics of a range vector (independent of their *value*)?

Comment: Is the part after "joba-" in `job_name` an id?
In other words: are you looking for a count increase olf existing job_name="joba-*" time series over time? (like: "if in total there were 3 "joba-*" time series and after 2 hours there are still 2 we have a problem"?)
When these time series disappear (stop being emitted by your exporter)?
What happens or should happen if the exporter (or the process it is monitoring) is restarted for any reason - will the old job_name values still there ot does it start from scratch?

Comment: @bjakubski sorry for the confusion. Yes, the suffix is a random, unique id. I want to know if a metric / time series with the id prefix `joba-` was *added* during the last 2 hours. The series might eventually disappear some time later (way after the 2h window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with something like:

```
count( 
  sometool_jobs_succeeded{job_name=~"joba-.+"} unless (sometool_jobs_succeeded{job_name=~"joba-.+"} offset 2h)                                                                                                                                                                   
)
```

This will return count of joba instances now, that were not present 2h ago

I'd consider if the exporter or app could be modifed so that they emit something like

```
sometool_jobs_succeeded{job_type="joba"} 8
```

So an ordinary counter per job type. This would be much more natural to use in Prometheus (and fit its data model better). It can be processed via an `increase` call and it would handle any resets etc.

Please note that having unique ids as label value is against recommendations.
Labels with big cardinality may cause issues (although unless scale is really big it can probably handle it).

Comment: just what I needed, I wasn't aware of `unless`, thanks. Unfortunately I can't modify how the Exporter works, so this is the best I can get :)